# Clicar em um botão que ainda não está na tela

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Recentemente decidi fazer uma automação usando Python com o módulo Selenium. Estava indo tudo bem até eu ter que simular um click em um botão que não está na tela no momento e o tempo dele aparecer varia com tempo de espera na fila, queria saber como fazer o webdriver esperar o botão aparecer para assim poder simular o click... Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grato!

OBS: Já tentei esse código: `confirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "confirm"))) confirm.click()`, mas não funcionou, sempre dá esse erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/lordvitor11/Área de Trabalho/Python/test.py", line 30, in 
> confirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "confirm")))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer esse código:

```
confirm = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "confirm"))) 
confirm.click()
```

provavelmente seu código não funcionou porque seu elemento *"confirm"* não estava alocado, ou seja você estava esperando o elemento se tornar clicável quando o elemento sequer existia na página.

Se for esse o seu problema você tem algumas opções:

Para esperar o elemento estar alocado mas não necessariamente visível use

```
EC.presence_of_element_located()
```

Para esperar o elemento estar alocado e visível use

```
EC.visibility_of_element_located()
```

A última opção me pareceu mais adequada de acordo com a sua pergunta.

Comment: Usei o código indicado e.... FUNCIONOU!! De início não estava funcionando li a mensagem de erro e percebi que o tempo que eu coloquei pra esperar não estava sendo suficiente, então eu aumentei o tempo e funcionou!! Muito obrigado mesmo!!! xD